# how to enable rightclick on wordpress when nothing gone wrong?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress-based site for my pal, and I've came across an strange issue - rightclick doesn't work on the production site.

It works fine on http://zombeck.stronazen.pl/music_studio/ but it doesn't on http://ezrec.pl/

I've copied css from the first one to the other one, the stucture of sites and the theme settings are all the same, but somehow the rightclick doesn't work. I didn't edit any JS/PHP/htaccess etc. because I just don't know how...

Any ideas why rightclick doesn't work on ezrec.pl?

Here's the code form style.css that I've added:

```
div#site-logo img { width: 250px !important; }

div#contactLocation div#contactLocation-contact {
width:45%;
box-sizing:border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left;
}

div#contactLocation div#contactLocation-location {
width:45%;
box-sizing:border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working just fine for me. Is there a specific thing you're trying to right-click on? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Wow, it's actually working now, but it wasn't working yesterday... Maybe it was some kind of glitch. Nevertheless thank you for your time and answer!